# Angular4 http post method does not pass data to web api

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

When I called the http post method it returns "data does not pass correctly".I passed data through body and I also tried by passing using  json.stringify() I also tried by using  content type as following also. But it didn't  work.

```
const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
this.http_.post('http://localhost:12412/api/employee', remark, options)
  .subscribe((data) => {console.log(data)})};
```

I attached the post call method in component.ts file below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Response, Headers, RequestOptions,Http} from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Time } from '@angular/common/src/i18n/locale_data_api';
import { NgbDateStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/ngb-date-struct';
import { NgbCalendar } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/ngb-calendar';
import {Ng2OrderModule} from 'ng2-order-pipe';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";
import { PostChangesService } from './PostChanges.service';
import { Body } from '@angular/http/src/body';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
})

export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private http_:Http){

  }

  EditValue(event,remark,log_id) {
    console.log(remark+" "+log_id );

    //  var headers = new Headers();
    //  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    //  var body="remark="+remark;
    //  //let body = JSON.stringify(remark);
    //    this.http_.post('http://localhost:12412/api/employee?',{body:remark},{headers:headers})
    // .subscribe((data) => {console.log(data)}
    // );
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    //const params = new URLSearchParams();

    // let body = JSON.stringify(remark);
   this.http_.post('http://localhost:12412/api/employee?',remark,options)
    .subscribe((data) => {console.log(data)} 
   )};  
  }
}
```

And the web api post method is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Post([FromBody]string remark)
{
    if (remark != null)
    {
        return remark + " _ " ;
    }
    else
        return "data doesn't pass correctly";
}
```

Comment: Is there any error ? post here plz

Comment: "remark" value does not pass to web api post method. when I compile the code it returns "data doesn't pass correctly".If it passes correctly need to return "remark" value I passed

Comment: `console.log(remark+" "+log_id );` printing desired value to console ?

Comment: Try posting data via POSTMAN or any client.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing your post data as object like this:

```
 // let body = JSON.stringify(remark);
 this.http_.post('http://localhost:12412/api/employee',{remark:remark},options)
   .subscribe((data) => {console.log(data)} 
 )};
```

**Web api post method**

```
[HttpPost]
public string Post([FromBody]RemarkModel model)
{
   if (model.remark != null)
   {
                return model.remark + " _ " ;
   }
   else
   {
    return "data doesn't pass correctly";             
   }
}

public class RemarkModel
{
   public string remark {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: @E.L.N.D.Madubhashini Can you try without the options parameter.

Comment: @AliShahzad OP should be able to send string value. I would consider class as a workaround.

Comment: I tried using above updated answer still didn't work.

Comment: have you removed the "?" from url?

Comment: I tried without using options parameter. It produce an error called "Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405."  and "options url 405 (method not allowed)"

Comment: I checked it by removing "?" in url also.

Comment: I tried it using Postman, data doesn't pass from that also.After I sent the request, in Body same message is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change your code to:

```
let body = {
   remark : remark
};

this.http_.post('http://localhost:12412/api/employee',JSON.stringify(body),options)
   .subscribe((data) => {console.log(data)});
```

No change Web API. It should be worked.

Comment: Didn't work for me.Still get that data does not pass message.

Answer (score 0):

**Import Headers from @angular/http**

```
Post=(url:string,data:any)=>{
    this.headers = new Headers();
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers, method: "post"}); 
    return this.http.post(
        url,
        data,
        options
    );
}
```

> It worked for me ;)

Comment: I added .subscribe((data) => {console.log(data)}  );
 to  above code to check those data are passing. Still not passing.

Comment: Do not subscribe directly to http post(its not reccomended), return data from post. Subscribe it as a common method. like....  this.httpservice.postdata().subscribe()