# Angular4 http post method pass empty values to web api

Tags: html, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I call http post method from angular4 component to web api. When I print those values return from web api on console it prints empty values. I checked the request using postman also. It also didn't work.

Http post call from component file.

```
EditValue(event, name, id) {
  const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
  const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  let body = { "name" : name, "id": id }
  this.http_.post('http://localhost:12412/api/employee?', body, options)
    .subscribe((data) => {console.log(data)});
}
```

Http post method in web api.

```
[HttpPost]            
public string postemp(Model model)
{
    return "name:" +model.name + " , " + "id: " + model.id;
}

public class Model
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

When I check the name and id from Editvalue function those values are passing. I tried solutions given by [Angular4 http post method does not pass data to web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144824/angular4-http-post-method-does-not-pass-data-to-web-api) also. But issue didn't fix.How to check those posted data is passing to web api post method?

I attached the response result I got below.

[image]

Comment: can you change the content-type ? ..,did you try that ?

Comment: Are you using HttpClient?

Comment: No.I used Http.

Comment: Did you check the incoming parameter values on your EditValue function? Can you try to log them in your console?

Comment: @E.L.N.D.Madubhashini is your question different from the question in [Angular4 http post method does not pass data to web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144824/angular4-http-post-method-does-not-pass-data-to-web-api)?

Comment: Editvalue function get those parameters correctly

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the info in the body in JSON format. But in your header you set `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in which the values are encoded in key-value tuples separated by '&', with a '=' between the key and the value. So, to be able to send the data in the JSON format you need to change the `Content-Type` in your header to `application/json`.

Comment: After I changing the content-type to application/json it gives error like "Failed to load http://localhost:12412/api/employee?: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405."

Comment: You need to use JSON.stringify() on the body element to get a JSON representation to use in the http post method.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `[FromBody]` attribute to your API method parameter like below.

```
[HttpPost]            
public string postemp([FromBody]Model model)
{
    return "name:" +model.name + " , " + "id: " + model.id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try `JSON.stringify(body)` before you send to the webapi once

Comment: Still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Since the content type I used here is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', body should not be passed using JSON object. Body I passed here should be in query string like below.

```html
let body="id="+id+"&name="+name;
```

It worked for me.